# How do I embed an attached file into the post in the single-template, after retrieving attachment from the $Post,

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom content type, called "sheets" with an XLS spreadsheet attached. 
I'm trying to now display the spreadsheet embedded into the post inside the single-sheets.php template.

I'm using Google Embedded Document plugin, which allows Excel spreadsheets to be embedded and displayed in a post through a shortcode inside the editor of a post, so I hope it's still possible to embed the document when the spreadsheet is added to the post manually in a custom field.

I have managed to retrieve the attachments and display just the link to download the spreadsheet, but I want the actual attachment to appear embedded into the post, Just like it would if I were to.

Here is a piece of the single-sheets.php template, what I have so far.

```
<?php
                    // place inside loop
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type' => 'application/zip, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/pdf',
                        'numberposts' => null,
                        'post_status' => null,
                        'post_parent' => $post->ID
                    );
                    $attachments = get_posts($args);
                    echo '<h3>Attached files</h3>';
                        if ($attachments) {
                            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                            the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

This returns a link to the spreadsheet to download the attachment, but it's not embedded in the post:

Attached files
Test Spreadsheet 2 - Link to spreadsheet download

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out haha, I had basically answered my own question here.
I just had to use wordpress function: do_shortcode()
and include the shortcode I needed which was [gview file="http://linkhere"];

This embedded the attachment, although the attachment_link() didnt work, I needed to get the GUID link instead.